# Org-gantt adds a week when calculating from effort estimate

Tags: elisp, org-mode, gantt-chart

Org-gantt seems to fulfill my gantt-chart creation needs. It works

- on an org-mode file
- with tasks of duration measured in less than days
- on effort estimates - or should do...

**It seems to have a bug though making it add a week when calculating the end or start date for a task with an effort estimate** and either a schedule or a deadline. Hense running the example from [section 3.2.1
 in the manual](https://github.com/CMJager/emacs-stuff/blob/373c4bbb0373ea6bd0bfe8838625db5452d828bc/experiments/org-gantt-manual.pdf#page=5) the resulting end date for *Weld Frame* is the 27th and not the 20th and the start date for *Paint Frame* is the 13th and not the 20th and so on:

```
#+BEGIN: org-gantt-chart :id "effort-src" :use-id-subheadlines t :start-date "2015-05-15" :end-date "2015-05-31"
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate, vgrid={*3{black},*4{dashed}}]{2015-05-15}{2015-05-31}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, day}\\
\ganttgroup[group left shift=0.0, group right shift=-0.0, name=uniqueid1]{Frame}{2015-05-19}{2015-05-21}\\
  \ganttbar[bar left shift=0.0, bar right shift=-0.0, name=uniqueid2]{Weld Frame}{2015-05-19}{2015-05-27}\\
  \ganttbar[bar left shift=0.0, bar right shift=-0.0, name=uniqueid3]{Paint Frame}{2015-05-13}{2015-05-21}\\
\ganttgroup[group left shift=0.0, group right shift=-0.0, name=uniqueid4]{Other Parts}{2015-05-22}{2015-05-27}\\
  \ganttbar[bar left shift=0.0, bar right shift=-0.625, name=uniqueid5]{Assemble Parts}{2015-05-22}{2015-06-02}\\
  \ganttbar[bar left shift=0.375, bar right shift=-0.0, name=uniqueid6]{Fix Parts to Frame}{2015-05-15}{2015-05-27}\\
\end{ganttchart}
#+END
```

Using only deadlines and schedules it works fine, but when using effort estimates it does not and **even when**

- changing the `hours-per-day`
- changing the `work-free-days`
- using effort estimates of several weeks
- using an effort estimate of `0d`

**it still gives an end date with 7 days added** when using `SCHEDULED` **or a start date with seven days withdrawn** when using `DEADLINE` in the org-file. Therefore it has to be when the effort is added or withdrawn the `SCHEDULED` or the `DEADLINE` date perhaps in the `org-gantt-calculate-ds-from-effort` function in the [org-gantt.el](https://github.com/CMJager/emacs-stuff/blob/373c4bbb0373ea6bd0bfe8838625db5452d828bc/experiments/org-gantt.el) file.

I am still a newbie in lisp programming and therefore I hope someone else can find where and what the problem is or what else to do (and perhaps make a suggestion at the repository to the author).

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: You should open an issue at https://github.com/HeyFlash/emacs-stuff/issues

Comment: BTW, which version of org-gantt.el do you have? There is a fix that was added 2 years ago that seems relevant to this bug: it subtracts seven days in certain circumstance (which I don't understand - I didn't really follow it in detail). The commit is https://github.com/HeyFlash/emacs-stuff/commit/373c4bbb0373ea6bd0bfe8838625db5452d828bc . I'm wondering if you have that commit or not in your version.

Comment: I have the commit and now have outcommented the line which subtracts the seven days. That seems to do the trick. (I too don't understand why it and wonder why it's been made.)

Comment: BTW, I'll open an issue as you suggest. Thanks.